# What is the smallest value of $x^x$ between $0$ and $1$?

Tags: real-analysis

The limit of $x^x$ goes to $1$ as we approach either $0$ or $1$, but I'm interested in the smallest possible value for $x^x$ in this interval. Is there a way to find this number, and is it rational?

Comment: Have you tried to ask Wolfram Alpha? [minimize x^x for 0 < x < 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+x%5Ex+for+0+%3C+x+%3C+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since $\frac{{\rm d}x^x}{{\rm d}x} = x^x (\ln(x)+1)$, we clearly have a critical point at $x = \frac 1e$. This gives rise to the minimum value $ e^{-\frac 1e}$, which is not rational.

Comment: I'm sure it is irrational, but is there a proof?

Comment: I was wondering about that as well. It should be possible to prove that but I don't have a proof at hand. Maybe someone else can give a pointer here.

Comment: According to Wolfram, it is unknown.

Comment: @Florian I guess it is open whether this number is rational.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\ln x^x=x\ln x$. Then
$f'(x)=1+\ln x$ which vanishes at $x=e^{-1}$. At $x=e^{-1}$,
$x^x=e^{-1/e}$. That is the minimum of $x^x$ on $[0,1]$.